# Liquid propellant rocket engine igniter

Tags: rockets, ignition

I have a project in which I will have to design a rocket engine igniter. It is for the big scale rockets for space missions. But, there is no information available on the internet regarding the igniter. I have only found a few research papers and nothing else. Please help me

Comment: This is still very, very vague. There are several completely different methods of igniting solid fuel and different kinds of liquid fuel rockets, and there is a fair amount of information out there about them. Detailed information on designing actual hardware may be encumbered by ITAR and stuff just being proprietary.

Comment: Have you searched this site for 'igniter"? There's quite a lot of info here, I have answered two or three questions on igniters myself. Consider reading all that stuff, then editing your question to be more specific.